# What is the appropriate webservice pattern in my situation and why?

Tags: c++, web-services, asynchronous, wsdl, gsoap

I need to implement web services in C++ using **gSoap**.

My situation is the following :

- I have some synchronous webservice operations.
- And I have as well some asynchronous web service operations.

For the asynchronous web service operations, I have for example this operation **StartCalculating** which:

- should send to the client a **synchronous response** that says **"Fine! I started calculating!"**;
- and which, **later**, should send to the client an **asynchronous response** that says **"Here, I've got the result of my calculations!"**

After searching in internet, I've found there are 4 patterns :

> **One-way:** The endpoint receives a message.
>
> **Request/response:** The endpoint receives a message, and sends a correlated message.
>
> **Solicit/response: (Request/reply operations with polling)** The endpoint sends a message, and receives a correlated message.
>
> **Notification: (Request/reply operations with posting)** The endpoint sends a message.

First of all, that term of "correlation" makes me confused (Correlation ID..).

Second, I still don't know which one is the appropriate for my need, having the constraint that the client would do only **1 operation call** for **2 results (synchronous response + asynchronous response)**.

Some hints as a projection on gSoap would be so appreciated. ( [Here](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/%7Eengelen/soapdoc2.html#sec:oneway2) they talk about the one way solution only, in gSoap documentation)

Thank you a lot!

Comment: I think you need to find your requirements first, as there are many volumes of computer science books that goes into depth with these software design patters.